# Convert an array elements into a hash ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of strings and want to convert it into a hash where
`array[0]` is the key and `array[1]` is the value then `array[2]` is the key for the next set.

I have tried `#each`, `#map`, `#each_with_object`, `#to_h` in all manner of combinations and the closest I can get is to set each array element to a key with nil value.

```rb
# animal_data1 ={}
# animal_data1 = Hash[collected.map {|key,value| [key.to_sym, value]}]
# puts animal_data1 

=> {
    :"Kingdom:Five groups that classify all living things"=>nil,
    :Animalia=>nil,
    :"Phylum:A group of animals within the animal kingdom"=>nil,
    :Chordata=>nil,
    :"Class:A group of animals within a pylum"=>nil,
    :Mammalia=>nil,
    :"Order:A group of animals within a class"=>nil,
    :Tubulidentata=>nil,
    :"Family:A group of animals within an order"=>nil
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
arr = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

```
Hash[*arr]
  #=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d}
```

See [Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

`Hash[*arr]` is here the same as:

```
Hash[:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to group the array into pairs, then use the first item of each pair as the key, and the second item as the value.

```
def array_to_hash(array)
  # Create a new hash to store the return value
  hash = {}

  # Slice the array into smaller arrays, each of length 2.
  array.each_slice(2) do |pair|

    # Get the key and value from the pair
    key = pair[0]
    value = pair[1]

    # Update the hash
    hash[key] = value
  end

  # Return the hash
  hash
end

array_to_hash([:a, :b, :c, :d]) #=> { :a => :b, :c => :d }
```

Comment: `array.each_slice(2) do |pair| ...` is sufficient (no need for `.each`). You might explain that `array.each_slice(2).with_object({}) { |(key, val),hash| hash[k] = val }` avoids the need for `hash = {}` at the beginning and `hash` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the redundant each, but I was trying to keep the quantity of new concepts here somewhat low for simplicity sake :) Good points, though.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I would suggest Alex Wayne's answer, there is another way you can approach this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
hash = {}
i = 0

while (i<array.length)
  hash[array[i] = array[i+1]
  i+=2
end

hash
```

[Sample demo](https://repl.it/@AdemDinarevic/Array-to-hash-Stackoverflow-example)